# Save pdf to desired location in device React Native

Tags: javascript, android, html, react-native, pdf

I'm using RNHTMLtoPDF from 'react-native-html-to-pdf' and I want to store to my desired location so what should I do? I have a path that is storage emulated and that path is saved in a hook but I want this pdf downloaded to be in my device storage. Any help regarding this matter would be highly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe add a standard 'share' component from react-native?

https://reactnative.dev/docs/share

and the logic is when you click on pdf or whatever button you have - the share component will be opened and then you'll choose where you want to put that file(also to save it on your phone)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm i react-native-fs` library for save in local devices

**Sample Code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

export default function App() {

  //if you want to save in download directory then you can use this path
  const path = RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath;

  const saveFile = () => {
    RNFS.copyFile(yourCurrentFilePath, yourDestinationFilePath);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => saveFile()}>
        <Text>Save</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

For More Information you can explore the react-native-fs library documents [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs)